# Парсим просмотры в базу данных

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Подскажите как парсить кол-во просмотров c сервиса Youtube.com определеного видео в базу данных. 
ну или подскажите как сделать счетчик просмотров видео.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/gdata/

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/C38VUyiQa00
```

вместо C38VUyiQa00 подставить id необходимого видео.

```
<yt:statistics favoriteCount="160" viewCount="100356"/>
```

А это уже совсем не сложно распарсить.